# Javascript newDate(datestring) seems to be changing my time zone

Tags: javascript, date

So I have a datestring that looks like

```
2014-08-02T19:00:00
```

Which should come out to **Aug 02 2014 7PM (EST)** but when I create a date object it seems to change it to

```
Sat Aug 02 2014 15:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Basically it seems to be assuming that the datestring was in GMT-0000. Is there a way for me to tell it the GMT of the datestring so it doesn't automatically adjust it?

Comment: **Do not** use the Date constructor to parse strings. That string will be parsed as UTC by some browsers (e.g. Firefox per ES5) and local by others (e.g. Chrome per the ES 6 draft) and fail completely in yet others to return `NaN` (e.g. IE 8). Parse the string yourself so that it is always one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your datestring *is* in GMT.

If your datestring actually is in EST, it should look like this:

```
2014-08-02T19:00:00-04:00
```

Specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15

Comment: Such a simple mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use the Date constructor to parse strings, it is largely implementation dependent. The above might have one of 3 different results in current browsers in use.

Comment: @RobG We're talking about standards here... Implementation differences in Date.parse only happen when a format is provided that does *not* adher to the standards. Unless you can give me a browser that incorrectly parses ISO dates *with* a timezone, this answer is correct...

Comment: @Bart—As I've pointed out, the format in the OP **is** treated differently by browsers in use and **is** treated differently in ECMAScript edition 3, edition 5 and the edition 6 draft. So event **standards compliant** browsers will treat it differently. The **only** timezone that is specified is UTC (Z), and even that will fail in browsers like IE 8 (which continues to have better than [*20% user share*](http://netmarketshare.com/#)).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the [Date constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) to parse strings (it [uses Date.parse](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2)).

An ISO 8601 format string with not timezone will be parsed as UTC by some browsers (e.g. Firefox per ES5) and local by others (e.g. Chrome per the ES 6 draft) and fail completely in yet others to return NaN (e.g. IE 8). Parse the string yourself so that it is always one or the other.

The following will parse it as UTC:

```
function parseISOUTC(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D+/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]));
}

console.log(parseISOUTC('2014-08-02T19:00:00').toISOString()); // 2014-08-02T19:00:00.000Z
```

Given the change in specification between ES5 and the edition 6 draft, event parsing the one format specified by ECMA-262 in the very latest browsers will remain problematic for some time.